# How to set line under UITabBarItem dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Here i want to show a line below the tabBarItem like shown in the below image [image] and i am setting it in a following way. However the problem is it is static one and if i use the bigger screen size like iPhone 6 plus the paintView2 moves and looks ugly. So, how to set the CGRectMake co-ordinates of view dynamically for all screen sizes. Have tried in many ways but couldn't achieve what i wanted.

[image]

```
    paintView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105,662,70, 5)];


    NSLog(@"position:%f",paintView2.frame.origin.x);

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self colorWithHexString:@"34A9C4"].CGColor,(id)[self colorWithHexString:@"36AC60"].CGColor, nil];
    gradient.frame = paintView2.bounds ;
    [paintView2.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    [self.view addSubview:paintView2];
```

Comment: you need to get width of screen and based on that you have to calculate single tab width and place your view on selected tab.

Comment: If you want to indicate the selected tab then you can do this using images for _Selected/Unselected_ states. Just add that line in the image for _Selected_ state and for _Unselected_ state keep it as it is right now. No fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here while allocating your view and giving the frame, you need to make it dynamic like

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat ScreenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
CGFloat ScreenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(screen);

paintView2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((ScreenWidth/4)*i,ScreenHeight - 5, ScreenWidth/4, 5)];
```

Comment: what is the screenWidth and I here

Comment: what is *i here

Comment: i will be the index of your selected TabBar starting from 0

Comment: no it is not working, not at proper position. Its coming at center.

Comment: not always but it is losing the x position, x is not proper

Comment: can you add that screenshot ?

Comment: and how it will for first tabBarItem, what change will be there for the first third and fourth tabBarItem

Comment: setting the index for each tab should set the line under each TabBarItem correctly but the code for the x position need to be corrected.

Comment: Upload a screenshot and share a link with me

Comment: see i have clicked on third tab and see the line is not at proper position

Comment: what about the fourth tab because the index value of fourth tab is 5

Comment: @Vicky the index value must start from 0,1,2 and go on, now why would the value of fourth tab is 5, I am not getting it